# Handling TCP and TLS together - golang

Tags: go, sockets, ssl, tcp

## Problem Description

I've been trying to handle TCP and TLS with one listener (the tcp listener) so that i can use the same port for both protocols (to reuse 443 and possibly bypass some firewall restrictions). I've come up with a solution and my question to you fine lads is that is there a better way to do this? And also is there any edge cases that my solution would not cover? Thanks in advance <3.

## My Solution

I've created a `customListener` that overloads `Accept()` method of `net.Listener`. In my version of `Accept()` i call the `net.Listener`'s `Accept()` method internally, and then pass the `conn` to `bufio.Reader` to utilize the `Peek()` method. Then i peek 6 bytes and check if the first byte is `0x16` (tls handshake record) and the sixth byte to be `0x01` (tls client hello). If so, I create a `tls.Conn` by calling `tls.Server()` and passing my `bufferedConn` (which is a wrapper around `net.Conn` which overload `Read()` method. And if not, just return `bufferedConn`. One downside is that if you are only using tcp, You have to write at least 6 bytes so the call to `Peek()` would return.

## Code Samples

```golang
type customListener struct {
    net.Listener
    cert tls.Certificate
}

func NewTLSAndTCPTransport(bindAddress, certFile, keyFile string, port uint16) net.Listener {
    var (
        tcpListener net.Listener
        cert tls.Certificate
    )
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("failed to create cert: %v", err))
    }

    if tcpListener, err = net.Listen("tcp4", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", bindAddress, port)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("failed to create tcp listener: %v", err))
    }
    
    cuListener := customListener{
        Listener: tcpListener,
        cert:     cert,
    }

    return &cuListener
}

func (li *customListener) Accept() (net.Conn, error) {
    c, err := li.Listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    buffConn := newBufferedConn(c)
    b, err := buffConn.Peek(6)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if isTLS(b) {
        return li.tlsConn(buffConn), nil
    } else {
        return buffConn, nil
    }
}

func (li *customListener) tlsConn(conn net.Conn) net.Conn {
    newConn := tls.Server(conn, &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{
            li.cert,
        },
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
    })

    return newConn
}

func isTLS(b []byte) bool {
    cond := b[0] == 0x16 && b[5] == 0x01
    return cond
}

type bufferedConn struct {
    r *bufio.Reader
    net.Conn
}

func newBufferedConn(conn net.Conn) *bufferedConn {
    return &bufferedConn{
        r:    bufio.NewReader(conn),
        Conn: conn,
    }
}

func (b *bufferedConn) Peek(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    return b.r.Peek(n)
}

func (b *bufferedConn) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return b.r.Read(p)
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS

Comment: Hey @MaartenBodewes, Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm not interested in higher layer application protocols. I want to use either the plain tcp socket or use tls on top of it.

Comment: I don't know what other protocols are put on top of it, but the obvious issue is that you might mistake a plain TCP connection for TLS. Preferably you'd have something like a large magic to validate, having just a few bytes is not 100% secure. If you have a pure text protocol or a protocol with textual headers then 0x16 and 0x01 will be unlikely of course.

Comment: Oh i see. I'm trying to handle TURN/tls and TURN/tcp with the one tcp listener. How about i check tls version and some other tls specific headers? I think there wil be room for false positives anyways, right? What do you suggest?

Comment: *possibly bypass some firewall restrictions*  Firewalls can and do perform packet inspection.  I'd imagine it wouldn't be hard to configure any decent firewall to reject non-TLS connection attempts, especially if the non-TLS connection attempt is to a normal TLS-enabled port such as 443.

Comment: My former ISP famously ran SSH on port 443, it usually worked *fine*. Saved my butt multiple times when I had to do a hotel booking that got blocked :)

Comment: @itsloop I don't know enough about TURN to know, but I guess if you can distinguish between TURN/TCP and TLS then you should be fine. It's a bit protocol specific maybe and although I see some messages, I'm not sure if it can be distinguished always.

Comment: I added tls version as well. I think this would handle most situations. 
```cond := b[0] == 0x16 && b[5] == 0x01 && (int(binary.BigEndian.Uint16(b[1:3])) >= li.minTlsVersion)```

Comment: I have tested in a production server and after a while many TCP connections will stuck in TIME_WAIT state and the server will refuse to accept any new connections. I haven't tested this any more but I will soon and share my results.